# Is it possible to remove trailing/leading whitespace characters from Angular's compiled templates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

As of [Angular 5](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced), we can now choose whether or not to [preserve whitespace](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserveWhitespaces) coming from our components and application by setting this in tsconfig.json:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  },
```

The same can be specified in the decorator of each component. However, adjacent trailing/leading whitespaces are replaced with one space:

> Series of whitespaces in text nodes are replaced with one space (ex.: `<span>\n some text\n</span> will be converted to <span> some text </span>`);

Is there a way to completely remove leading and trailing whitespaces from text nodes?

Comment: \s includes \n . This is expected behaviour, and the manual states this explicitly. If this is the case for you, I'd suggest to open an issue in Angular repo.

Comment: The issue was actually related to trailing/leading series of white spaces inside text nodes. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Removing spaces completely will affect the layout. `<span>foo</span><span> bar</span>` would result in `foobar` and not `foo bar`. I don't think anyone wants it to happen automatically.